# How to select a row with maximum value for a column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max

*None of other available answers solved my problem

I have a table t like this

```
 id,cc,count
'1','HN','22'
'1','US','18'
'1','VN','1'
'2','DK','2'
'2','US','256'
'3','SK','1'
'3','US','66310'
'4','UA','2'
'4','US','263'
'6','FR','7'
'6','US','84'
'9','BR','3'
```

I want to get the rows for ids with maximum count, like below:

```
 id,cc,count
'1','HN','22'
'2','US','256'
'3','US','66310'
'4','US','263'
'6','US','84'
'9','BR','3'
```

My current code is like this but I am not getting the expected results:

```
SELECT t.* FROM  t
     JOIN (
       SELECT 
    t.id,t.cc
    ,max(t.count) as max_slash24_count
    FROM t 
    group by t.id,t.cc
      ) highest
     ON t.count = highest.max_slash24_count
  and t.cc = highest.cc
```

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Looks like you need to remove the group by `t.cc` from the subquery and then join back to your table on the `max_slash24_count` and the `id`.

Comment: Just remove the references to `t.cc` from the inline view query (from the GROUP BY clause and the SELECT list), then your query is good to go. If there is more than one row for a given id with the same highest value of `count`, your query will return all the rows with that same highest `count` value. If you want to ensure only a single row returned per `id` value, you'd need to add a `GROUP BY t.id` on the outermost query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `CC` column from `group by`. Try this.

```
SELECT t.* FROM  t
     JOIN (
       SELECT 
    t.id
    ,max(t.count) as max_slash24_count
    FROM t 
    group by t.id
      ) highest
     ON t.count = highest.max_slash24_count
  and t.id= highest.id
```

Comment: Thanks @NoDisplayName . This still does not work cause still I see two rows for one id.

Comment: @ Andrey the number of rows that I get as the result is 300 more than the table distinct rows for id column. That is how I know something is wrong

Comment: @user2058811 - then for same `id` more than one `cc` column is having maximum value but in you sample data it is not the case.

Comment: @user2058811 If your assertion is true, then you have no PRIMARY KEY. This is a problem!!

Comment: @NoDisplayName Indeed. I did not controlled for those that are equal numbers for the cc column and thus no Max

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
create table t (id varchar(10), cc varchar(10), count varchar(10))

insert into t (id,cc,count) values ('1','HN','22');
insert into t (id,cc,count) values ('1','US','18');
insert into t (id,cc,count) values ('1','VN','1');
insert into t (id,cc,count) values ('2','DK','2');
insert into t (id,cc,count) values ('2','US','256');
insert into t (id,cc,count) values ('3','SK','1');
insert into t (id,cc,count) values ('3','US','66310');
insert into t (id,cc,count) values ('4','UA','2');
insert into t (id,cc,count) values ('4','US','263');
insert into t (id,cc,count) values ('6','FR','7');
insert into t (id,cc,count) values ('6','US','84');
insert into t (id,cc,count) values ('9','BR','3');

select *
from t
where exists (
    select *
    from t as t1
    group by t1.id
    having t1.id = t.id and max(t1.count) = t.count
)
```

Result

```
ID  CC  COUNT
-------------
1   HN  22
2   US  256
3   US  66310
4   US  263
6   US  84
9   BR  3
```

Check [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ede69/2)

Comment: @ Andrey what is t1 here?

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered a lot of times on SO. The query is as simple as this:

```
SELECT m.id, m.cc, m.count
FROM t m                         # "m" from "max"
    LEFT JOIN t b                # "b" from "bigger"
        ON m.id = b.id           # match a row in "m" with a row in "b" by `id`
        AND m.count < b.count    # match only rows from "b" having bigger count
WHERE b.count IS NULL            # there is no "bigger" count than "max"
```

The real issue on your question is about the column types. If `count` is `char` (and not `int`) then the string comparison happens using the dictionary order, not the numeric order.

For example, if the third row reads:

```
'1','VN','123'
```

you might expect it to be selected in the output, because `123` is bigger than `22`. This does not happen because, as string, `'123'` is smaller than `'22'`.

Answer (score 0):

Even tho, this was already answered, using [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) functionality as in SQL Server is quite fun and interesting: please look at this query:

```
SELECT TT.Id, TT.cc, TT.count
FROM (
SELECT t.cc
  , t.count
  , @row_number:=CASE WHEN @Id=Id THEN @row_number+1 ELSE 1 END AS row_number
  , @Id:=Id AS Id
FROM t, (SELECT @row_number:=0, @Id:='') AS temp
ORDER BY t.Id, t.count DESC
    ) AS TT
WHERE TT.row_number = 1
ORDER BY TT.Id;
```

It produces expected output:

```
| Id | cc | count |
|----|----|-------|
|  1 | HN |    22 |
|  2 | US |   256 |
|  3 | US | 66310 |
|  4 | US |   263 |
|  6 | US |    84 |
|  9 | BR |     3 |
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bae7/22)

I've taken test data from [@Andrey Morozov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27801412/3680098)